# How to get slave machine to connect to client on WSL machines JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter, rmi

I am trying to do distributed load testing on my network. I have two computers running WSL2 and the firewall is turned off on both of them. I am using OpenJDK version 1.8.0_292 on both WSLs. The Jmeter version on both systems is 5.4.2. I have server.rmi.ssl.disable=true in both Jmeter.properties files. I can access the web application when I type 192.168.1.6:4080 in my browser's URL on my computer running on 192.168.1.18.

The jmeter.properties file for the computer running the web application has remote_hosts=192.168.1.18

The jmeter.properties file for the computer that will be the slave machine has server.rmi.localport=4000

One of my Computers is running the web application and will also be running the client (i.e. ./jmeter). In the Jmeter test plan, the HTTP Request Defaults have the server name 192.168.1.6 and the port as 4080. My other computer has the IPv4 address of 192.168.1.18.

I start the slave machine first by entering `./jmeter-server -n -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.1.18 -X` and the following is outputted `Created remote object: UnicastServerRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[192.168.1.18:4000](local),objID:[-5f7e0f00:17ab805fd23:-7fff, -5246535002214415146]]]`

Now I start the client by entering './jmeter -n -t ~/test_plan.jmx -l ~/result.jtl -X -r '. On the slave machine I get

```
Starting the test on host 192.168.1.18 @ Sat Jul 17 22:02:16 PDT 2021 (1626584536943)
Finished the test on host 192.168.1.18 @ Sat Jul 17 22:03:25 PDT 2021 (1626584605136)
```

And on the client machine I get

```
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using /home/jasperhale/test_plan.jmx
Configuring remote engine: 192.168.1.18
Starting distributed test with remote engines: [192.168.1.18] @ Sat Jul 17 22:10:44 PDT 2021 (1626585044116)
Remote engines have been started:[192.168.1.18]
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
```

The problem is that after the slave finishes, the client does not stop and report results. When I inspect the `jmeter-server.log` file I get this error message

```
2021-07-17 22:56:22,545 ERROR o.a.j.s.RemoteListenerWrapper: testStarted(host) on 192.168.1.18
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.1.6; nested exception is:
2021-07-17 22:11:50,420 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Test Ended on 192.168.1.18
2021-07-17 22:11:50,420 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Test Ended on 192.168.1.18
2021-07-17 22:11:52,481 ERROR o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: testEnded(host)
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.1.6; nested exception is:
```

the error message is way bigger but the main issue is the connection refused

the slave machine is making requests from the test_plan. Also mode=Standard in both properties files. The report files I am trying to collect are the aggregate report, view results tree, and summary report. I've been stuck on this for a while, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

WSL uses a different IPv4 Address and I was getting those addresses by entering ipconfig into a windows command prompt. I tried it on windows not WSL and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try explicitly setting `client.rmi.localport` property on both master and slave machines to some free port which is not used by any other process like:

   ```
   client.rmi.localport=1234
   ```
2. Double check that you can reach this host and port from the slave using [telnet](https://www.acronis.com/en-us/articles/telnet/) or [netcat](https://www.tecmint.com/check-remote-port-in-linux/) or whatever command is there
3. Once you will be able to reach out from the slave to the master and from the master to the slave your distributed setup should start working normally

More information:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing with Docker](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-distributed-testing-with-docker)

Also having JMeter and the system under test running on the same host is not something you should be normally doing, JMeter can be very resource intensive and you may run into a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) when both JMeter and the system under test will be struggling for the operating system resources (CPU, RAM, etc.) so test results might be inaccurate